# Controller logic for on-click events used with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am interested making a feature similar to that of SO's, where an user who has asked a question could select an answer from a list of responses, but am stuck on how to handle the click events from the controller perspective.

Currently, I have the models `Question`, which `has_many` `answers`.  Additionally, I have made an `Selection` model, which is meant to symbolize the answer selection, where each `Question` only could `has_one` selected answer.

I render each questions's answers along with the question in the question's `show` action.  In my `_answer` partial, I want to place the following logic: "if the user who has asked the question is logged on, he could see links to 'unselect' the answer *if* the related `selection` has that answer's `answer_id` already stored (in other words, marking that this answer was previously selected), pr otherwise he could 'select' the answer which stores the answer's `answer_id` in `selection`.  (I should mention that I adapted most of the code below from [Rails tutorial](https://github.com/schneems/reddit_on_rails/blob/master/part_two_comments_and_votes.md) here, where I (unfortunately) don't quite have a solid understanding how to use `POST` to match or assign attributes to an instance variable )

```
  <% if current_user?(answer.question.user) %>
    <% if current_user.selections.where(:answer_id => answer.id) == answer.id %>
      <%= link_to "unselect", selections_path(:selection => {:answer_id => nil}), :method => :post %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "select", selections_path(:selection => {:answer_id => answer.id}), :method => :post %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

My roadblock is in the controller, where I'm stuck on how to use `the create` method to assign the `@selection` variable to a new `answer_id` if the user selects a new answer via the "select" link. Any help, or any guides on how to write on-click events would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: i don't understand what you want to achieve. Is it the onClick ajax call that is a problem, or the controller-side logic ?
Also, sorry to ask this, but just to be sure - are you aware that client-side and server-side are totally decoupled, and that any interaction between the two requires a new request ?

Comment: Yes - at the present I am writing them as new request rather than Ajax (i.e. the "viewcount" for a page would go up if the user selects an answer).  My question relates to the controller-side logic, and specifically what I should write in my `create` action.  I hope this help clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many different ways to do this, but i tend to think that **you have a design problem** here, so here's how i would do it.

I assume from what you said that your associations look like this :

```
 __________                                  ________
| Question |1                              *| Answer |
|          |<-------------------------------|        |
|          |1     * ___________ *          1|        |
|          |<------| Selection |----------->|________|
|          |       |           |            
|          |       |           |*          1 ________
|          |       |___________|----------->| User   |
|          |*                              1|        |
|__________|------------------------------->|________|
```

This visual representation clearly shows the problem : your `Selection` model is redundant, as it represents the fact that a question `belongs_to` a `User` (which we already know) ; it would not be redundant if there could be multiple selections for each couple of `Question / User`, but in practice we **want** that selection to be unique for each couple...

A `belongs_to` relation between `Question` and `Answer` would achieve the same thing that your `Selection` model does, and in fact *it would do it better* because you won't need all the logic to find the right selection, and to ensure it is unique / that the user is the rightfull owner of the question, etc.

So here's what i'd do :

- In the `Question` model

  ```
  has_many   :answers,         inverse_of: :question
  belongs_to :accepted_answer, class_name: :answer, foreign_key: :accepted_answer_id
  ```
- In the `Answer` model

  ```
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answers

  def accepted?
    return false if new_record? 
    question.try( :accepted_answer_id ) == id
    # an alternative is to use question.try( :accepted_answer ) == self
  end
  ```
- In your routes

  ```
  resources :questions do
    member do 
      # we use put because these are update actions
      put :accept_answer
      put :clear_accepted_answer
    end
  end
  ```
- In your `QuestionsController`

  ```
  respond_to :js, only: [:accept_answer, :clear_accepted_answer]

  def accept_answer
    @question = Question.find( params[:id] )

    # ...cue some logic to ensure current_user 
    # has required rights to update the question

    if @question.update_attributes( accepted_answer_id: params[:answer_id] )
      # ...render the js that updates your view (for example, 
      # find and replace calling link with an "unselect" one )
    else
      # .. an error has occurred, render an "unprocessable entity" status
    end
  end


  def clear_accepted_answer
    @question = Question.find( params[:id] )

    # ...cue some logic to ensure current_user 
    # has required rights to update the question

    if @question.update_attributes( accepted_answer_id: nil )
      # ...render the js that updates your view (for example, 
      # find and replace calling link with a "select" one )
    else
      # .. an error has occurred, render an "unprocessable entity" status
    end
  end
  ```
- in your view

  ```
    <% if current_user?(answer.question.user) %>
      <% if answer.accepted?  %>
        <%= link_to "unselect", 
                    clear_accepted_answer_question_path( answer.question ),
                    method: :put,
                    remote: true %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "select", 
                    accept_answer_question_path( 
                      answer.question, 
                      answer_id: answer.id 
                    ), 
                    method: :put,
                    remote: true %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your very well thought-out and crafted answer...I truly appreciate it.  I will certainly look to learn more about model relationships (I'm just seeing `inverse_of` for the first time now), and then update both my code as well as evaluate my other models to to see if they could benefit from better design.  Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome. For the record, `inverse_of` here is not absolutely necessary, but i tend to use it everywhere because (as i understand it) it prevents ActiveRecord from reloading an association when you do something like `question.answers.first.question` (where question would be reloaded save for the inverse_of)

Comment: It appears that `question.accepted_answer_id` isn't getting recognized (I get the "undefined method" error).  Changing it from `_id` to `.id` also resulted in an error, although it was "Called id for nil". I ensured that my `Question.rb` had the line `belongs_to :accepted_answer, class_name: :answer`, so I don't know why `accepted_answer` was not getting recognized when called from the view via `if answer.accepted?`.  Thanks for the help again.

Comment: hmmm... if your question has no accepted answer, it is normal that `accepted_answer.id` fails (use `accepted_answer.try(:id)` instead). What is strange though is that you get an undefined method for `accepted_answer_id`. How did you migrate ? what is the name of your FK field ? Oh nevermind - is this called when the record is new ? in this case, your answer could belong to no question, so use `question.try(:accepted_answer) == id` instead to nil-guard. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: This fixed it, although currently I am getting an mass assignment error. As you mentioned there ndeed be an migration error - should I have added `accepted_answer_id` as a column to my `Question.rb` model and then migrated?  (if not this could be one other step causing the issue).  Thanks again for following up :)

Comment: now that i think about this, another way do to this would be to add an "accepted" boolean field on the answers, with a unique constraint scoped on question_id. Would be more adequate if you want to find all accepted answers, but would be more tricky when you want to update the accepted answer.

Comment: my bad, i forgot that when you use `belongs_to class_name`, the foreign key used is based on the class provided. Add `foreign_key: 'accepted_answer_id'` to the belongs_to options and it should work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23455/discussion-between-daspianist-and-m-x)